# Nested divs. Autoset bottom div height according to top div size

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with fixed  height. Inside it I have two divs aligned to top and bottom. Top div has max-height and min-height. When it is a lot of text inside div in grows until max-height.

In this case bottom div should fill rest spaces of parent div when there is few data inside top div.

```css
.div1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 384px;
  min-height: 160px;
}
.div2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 202px;
}
.parent_el {
  height: 586px !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_el">
  <div class="div1" id=div1>
    Text. Here can be huge text also
  </div>
  <div id="map" class="div2">
    Here would be picture or map so it must grow in height when top div is small
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect case for a **[flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_flexbox_to_lay_out_web_applications)**:

```
.parent_el {
  display: flex;           /*make parent a flexbox*/
  flex-direction: column;  /*children should go down the page*/
}

.div2 {
  flex: 1;                 /*fill the rest of the container*/
}
```

Remove `position: absolute` and `width: 100%` as I've done in my Snippets.

**Snippet** demonstrating min-height:

```css
.parent_el {
  display: flex;           /*make parent a flexbox*/
  flex-direction: column;  /*children should go down the page*/
  height: 586px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-height: 384px;
  min-height: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.div2 {
  flex: 1;                 /*fill the rest of the container*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_el">
  <div class="div1">
    Text. Here can be huge text also
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    Here would be picture or map so it must grow in height when top div is small
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Snippet** demonstrating max-height:

```css
.parent_el {
  display: flex;           /*make parent a flexbox*/
  flex-direction: column;  /*children should go down the page*/
  height: 586px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-height: 384px;
  min-height: 160px;
  font: 50px arial;
  overflow: auto;
}

.div2 {
  flex: 1;                 /*fill the rest of the container*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_el">
  <div class="div1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    Here would be picture or map so it must grow in height when top div is small
  </div>
</div>
```